# Count Over returns Row_Number based on Order By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

Quick question based on some interesting syntax I've found out.
I have a table with these columns:

```
ID INT,
DimBuyDetails_Id INT, 
WeekOfBuy INT,
Spots INT,
Retired BIT
```

If I run this query I will get the `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of the `COUNT()`

```
SELECT *
    , COUNT(ID) OVER (
        PARTITION BY DimBuyDetails_Id, WeekOfBuy
        ORDER BY ID --<
) AS ct
FROM Core.FactBuysPerWeek
```

However, if I change the `ORDER BY` clause I'll get the `COUNT()`

```
SELECT *
    , COUNT(ID) OVER (
        PARTITION BY DimBuyDetails_Id, WeekOfBuy
        ORDER BY DimBuyDetails_Id, WeekOfBuy --<Changed Order by here
) AS ct
FROM Core.FactBuysPerWeek
```

Anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I run this query I will get the ROW_NUMBER() instead of the COUNT()

[OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms189461%28v%3dsql.110%29#general-remarks)

> If ORDER BY is not specified entire partition is used for a window frame. This applies only to functions that do not require ORDER BY clause. **If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame.** This applies only to functions that have can accept optional ROWS/RANGE specification.